# scipy.signal.freqs error array is to big

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, frequency

I'm trying to calculate the frequency response in the S plain.
When I input two arrays sizes of 4000 and 288000 I get a ValueError from the function.

My question is how can I chop this down to smaller size and still get the full data.

Here is a sample code:

```
from numpy import linspace, sin
from sicpy.signal import freqs
a = linspace(0, 100, 4000)
b = sin(linspace(0, 100, 288000)
h, w = freqs(a, b)
```

By the way this works when using freqz.

Comment: Your code indicates that do not have a clear understanding of what the input and output of `freqs` (and `freqz`) represent. Please study carefully the documentation.

Comment: the inputs must be powers of ten not the actual numbers.